# The composition of a Hermitian operator and a positive definite operator has real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, positive-definite

Can someone help with this... please

Suppose $X$ is a unitary space (i.e. a complex inner product space), $A$ is Hermitian, and $B$ is a positive definite linear transformation on $X$. Prove that the composite transformation $A\circ B$ has real eigenvalues.

Comment: Sounds dumb, but: does $A\cdot B$ mean the matrix product or the elementwise product?

Comment: @kimchilover That's no a dot. It's a tiny circle.

Comment: It means composition of two linear transformations

Answer (score 1):

Hint: When $B$ is positive definite, it has a 'square-root'. You may find a matrix $C$  so that $B=C^*C$. Now, show that if $AB x=\lambda x$ then $Cx$ is the eigenvector of a Hermitian matrix (which one?), also with eigenvalue $\lambda$ which therefore must be real.